# Ajax string comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, string

I have a basic ajax function

```
 setInterval(function() {
      var action = '';
      var status = '';
      $('#php-data').load('../Data/Dashboard.Data.php'); 
      $.ajax({type: 'POST', url: 'Data/Dashboard.Image.php', data: { json: action }, dataType: 'json' }).done(function(data) {
          console.log('Ajax Data: ' + data);
          status = JSON.parse(data);
          **if(status === 'false') {**
              console.log("script is NOT running");
              drawPieChart();
          } else {
              console.log("script is running");
            $('#php-image').load('../Data/Dashboard.Image.php'); //todo only load this is the ajax returned from Dashboard.image.php is true
          }
      });            
  }, 5000);
```

basically the only thing my ajax returns is "false" so when I compare status to false it should be true and drawPieChart(); but instead it always runs the jquery load() function even though my ajax data is returning false every single time. 
ive also tried this:

```
 setInterval(function() {
      var action = '';
      var status = '';
      $('#php-data').load('../Data/Dashboard.Data.php'); 
      $.ajax({type: 'POST', url: 'Data/Dashboard.Image.php', data: { json: action }, dataType: 'json' }).done(function(data) {
          console.log('Ajax Data: ' + data);
          status = data;
          **if(status === 'false') {**
              console.log("script is NOT running");
              drawPieChart();
          } else {
              console.log("script is running");
            $('#php-image').load('../Data/Dashboard.Image.php'); //todo only load this is the ajax returned from Dashboard.image.php is true
          }
      });            
  }, 5000);
```

and this :

```
 setInterval(function() {
      var action = '';
      $('#php-data').load('../Data/Dashboard.Data.php'); 
      $.ajax({type: 'POST', url: 'Data/Dashboard.Image.php', data: { json: action }, dataType: 'json' }).done(function(data) {
          console.log('Ajax Data: ' + data);
          **if(data == 'false') {**

              console.log("script is NOT running");
              drawPieChart();
          } else {
              console.log("script is running");
            $('#php-image').load('../Data/Dashboard.Image.php'); //todo only load this is the ajax returned from Dashboard.image.php is true
          }
      });            
  }, 5000);
```

Comment: What *exactly* do you see from your `console.log`?  What is your PHP code outputting?

Comment: It is returning this over and over again beacause of the setInterval(): Ajax Data: false                                                                                                             
 script is running

Comment: try `if (data == false) {`

Comment: why the quote in **'false'**, i think u have to check with **false** value direclty

Comment: it worked! i feel dumb thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(status === 'false')
```

This suggests a string. use this instead:

```
if(status == false)
```

you could simplify it even further like so:

```
if(!status)
```

Comment: that was the issue thank you! My ajax returned a string why did jquery or javascript automatically convert its type into a boolean?

Comment: if it's returning a string then it'd be true. if its returning nothing, or actually false, then it'd return false.